# ICO - can I block transaction before certain date?

Tags: transfer, ico

Is it possible the following: A person send EOS to a contract account before certain date, and the tokens are rejected?
Or I have to watch all the transactions and if they do not meet the criteria, I have to return the tokens as a second transaction paying for cpu and bandwidth?